# Data cannot be shared between activity and fragment and cannot communicate

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel

Data cannot be shared between activity and fragment and cannot communicate
Activity cannot observe fragment data
[Communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/fragments/communicate)

ViewModel

```
  class BlankViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableSelectedItem = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val onCallbackToDestroyFragment: LiveData<String?> = mutableSelectedItem
    fun selectItem(tag: String?) {
        mutableSelectedItem.value = tag
    }
    }
```

2 Fragment

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = BlankFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: BlankViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BlankViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.selectItem("data")
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, container, false)
}
}
```

3 Activity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(BlankViewModel::class.java)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(binding.fl.id, BlankFragment()).commit()

        viewModel.onCallbackToDestroyFragment.observe(this , Observer {
            Log.e("观察到了吗","Did you observe the data?")
        })
    }


}
```

There is no data in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new instance of the ViewModel in the fragment.

If you want the activity and fragment to share the same instance of the ViewModel you have to use.

`private lateinit var viewModel: BlankViewModel by activityViewModels()`

and remove the providers declaration in the fragment
.. Or you can create a customViewModel Factory and share that .

Comment: Thank you, your statement is correct, it is to get the activity